# Select statement with or operator

Tags: php, mysql

Let say if i've database row `settings [id,user,pass,sos]`

I've the following mysql statement

`$username` and `$password` could be anything whatever

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE user='$username' AND pass='$password'")
```

i want to say

```
SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE user='$username' AND pass='$password' or sos=$username and sos=$password
```

so my question is how to use `or` within select statement

like i wanna say

```
user='$username'
pass='$password'
or
sos = both $username and $password
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: what is sos? how can you have one filed with 2 different value?

Comment: this is just an example for simplicity then i'll apply it for my case :) ~thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use some brackets to make sure you are correctly matching on related username/password pairs:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `settings` 
WHERE (user='$username' AND pass='$password') 
    or (sos='$username' and sos='$password')
```

However, you really need to use parameterized queries as the above is subject to SQL injection attack. See here for some examples on how to do this:

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
SELECT * 
FROM `settings` 
WHERE (user='$username' AND pass='$password') or (sos='$username' and sos='$password')
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need some parenthetical groups.  I added single quotes in the second group, where you were initially missing them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `settings`
WHERE 
  (user='$username' AND pass='$password')
  OR (sos='$username' AND sos='$password')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `settings` 
WHERE 
   (user='$username' AND pass='$password')
   OR
   (sos='$username' AND sos='$password')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need parenthesis

```
SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE (user='$username' AND pass='$password') or (sos=$username and sos=$password)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it not work exactly like that? I would write

```
WHERE (user = '$username' AND pass = '$password')
OR ('$username' = '$password' AND sos = '$username');
```